# How can i save a file in python that is uploaded from a Filechooser and save it to a folder?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to python and I'm trying to save a file that is picked from the file chooser to an image folder.

here is some of the code:

```
def open_file(self):
    root = tk.Tk()
    # hides tk main window
    root.withdraw()
    canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=0, height=0)
    canvas1.pack()

    self.jpg = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file",
                                          filetypes=(("jpeg files", "*.jpg"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    FrameDesign.selected(self, self.jpg)
    root.destroy()
    return self.jpg

   # path = 'C:/Users/AJONES2/Desktop/img'
  #  fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)

   img.save('C:/Users/AJONES2/Documents/img', 'JPEG')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get info of a file selected with fileChooser in Kivy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735498/how-do-i-get-info-of-a-file-selected-with-filechooser-in-kivy)

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is called creating a minimal, reproducible example (reprex), a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve), or a minimal, workable example (mwe). - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example